# Pandas: How do I return a row value once a column reaches a certain value of another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, time

Here is a sample of the data:

[image]

**Goal:**
create a new timestamp column for when `running_bid_max` **greater than or equal** to the value in `ask_price_target_good`. Then create a separate timestamp column for when `running_bid_min` is **less than or equal to** `ask_price_target_bad`.

**Note**: This will be performed on a large amount of data and needs calculated as fast as possible.  I'm hoping I don't have to iterate through all rows via `iterrows()`

`running_bid_min` and `running_bid_max` are calculated using a `running.min()` and `pd.running.max()` from a certain time frame in the future (this example is using a 5 minute timeline. So it will be the running min,max 5 minutes from the current time)

copy the data below and then use `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')`

```
   time,bid_price,ask_price,running_bid_max,running_bid_min,ask_price_target_good,ask_price_target_bad
2019-07-24 07:59:44.432034,291.06,291.26,291.4,291.09,291.46,291.06
2019-07-24 07:59:46.393418,291.1,291.33,291.4,291.09,291.53,291.13
2019-07-24 07:59:48.425615,291.1,291.33,291.4,291.09,291.53,291.13
2019-07-24 07:59:50.084206,291.12,291.33,291.4,291.09,291.53,291.13
2019-07-24 07:59:52.326455,291.12,291.33,291.4,291.09,291.53,291.13
2019-07-24 07:59:54.428181,291.12,291.33,291.4,291.09,291.53,291.13
2019-07-24 07:59:58.550378,291.14,291.35,291.4,291.2,291.55,291.15
2019-07-24 08:00:00.837238,291.2,291.35,291.4,291.2,291.55,291.15
2019-07-24 08:00:57.338769,291.4,291.46,291.51,291.4,291.66,291.26
2019-07-24 08:00:59.058198,291.4,291.46,291.96,291.4,291.66,291.26
2019-07-24 08:01:00.802679,291.4,291.46,291.96,291.4,291.66,291.26
2019-07-24 08:01:02.781289,291.4,291.46,291.96,291.45,291.66,291.26
2019-07-24 08:01:04.645144,291.45,291.46,291.96,291.45,291.66,291.26
2019-07-24 08:01:06.491997,291.45,291.46,292.07,291.45,291.66,291.26
2019-07-24 08:01:08.586688,291.45,291.46,292.1,291.45,291.66,291.26
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to include **images** of sample data. You should print the data head to terminal and copy/paste it instead. That way people can try their code on the data and help you much better.

Comment: @QuangHoang I updated with printed data and it's formatted the best I could get it. I can't get any other rows to shift over without it off-shifting. Feel free to try and fix it if you want. Should be easy to shift the values in the last 2 columns over outside of stackoverflow.

Comment: it's much better now. I can copy and reproduce the dataframe with one command.

Comment: What if the reverse happens first? Do you want *that* timestamp or do you want nothing?

Comment: Also can you clarify your desired output for this data? Your first condition occurs at index 9, and your second occurs at index 1, so the first *does not* occur before the second.

Comment: @user3483203 the answer is updated. It will be easier to create 2 separate columns for the min and max. So to answer your second question, I would create a new column that has the timestamp from the first condition (index 9), then another columns for the second condition that I would fill with the timestamp from index 1.

From there, I can easily determine which one occurred first instead of trying to do all that in one column.

Comment: @bbennett36 but my code gives you exactly that: First column has first stamp at index 9 and second column has first stamp at index 1?

Comment: @QuangHoang can you show me a screenshot of your results? I'm not getting that result. I'm only getting the timestamp for the current row. Not the timestamp from index 9.

Comment: You want time stamp at index 9 filled in row 0?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Comment: with the explanation you have provided, it would be good if you can show us how the expected output should look like

Comment: what is the shape of your DataFrame ? (from real data)

Comment: Hello, did you find the solution for this? Please share

Comment: @ZeroPanda - I'm almost positive the most upvoted answer was the solution I used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From your question:

> creating a new timestamp column for when `running_bid_max` greater than
>   or equal to the value in `ask_price_target_good`. Then create a separate
>   timestamp column for when `running_bid_min` is less than or equal to
>   `ask_price_target_bad`

the problem seems trivial:

```
df['g'] = np.where(df.running_bid_max.ge(df.ask_price_target_good), df['time'], pd.NaT)

df['l'] = np.where(df.running_bid_min.le(df.ask_price_target_bad), df['time'], pd.NaT)
```

Or am I missing something?

---

Update: you might want to `ffill` and `bfill` after the above commands:

```
df['g'] = df['g'].bfill()
df['l'] = df['l'].ffill()
```

Output, for example `df['g']`:

```
0    2019-07-24 08:00:59.058198
1    2019-07-24 08:00:59.058198
2    2019-07-24 08:00:59.058198
3    2019-07-24 08:00:59.058198
4    2019-07-24 08:00:59.058198
5    2019-07-24 08:00:59.058198
6    2019-07-24 08:00:59.058198
7    2019-07-24 08:00:59.058198
8    2019-07-24 08:00:59.058198
9    2019-07-24 08:00:59.058198
10   2019-07-24 08:01:00.802679
11   2019-07-24 08:01:02.781289
12   2019-07-24 08:01:04.645144
13   2019-07-24 08:01:06.491997
14   2019-07-24 08:01:08.586688
```

Comment: I think this is only checking the values in the same row. I need it to check for dates in the future and not only the current row.

So for example, if you took the values at index 0. I would want to return the timestamp from index 1 for "running_bid_max" being greater than or equal to the value in "ask_price_target_good"

In the data above, index 0 wouldn't be able to return a timestamp for "running_bid_min" being less than or equal to "ask_price_target_bad" because that never happens after that time.

Answer (score 5):

It would be very nice if you could print the desired output. Otherwise I may miss the logic.

If you are working on large amount of data, it makes sense to apply [steaming analytics](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/streaming-analytics.html)*. (This will quite memory efficient and if you use `cytoolz` even 2-4 times faster)

So basically you would like to *partition* your data based on either one or the other condition:

```py
partitions = toolz.partitionby(lambda x: (x['running_bid_max'] >= x['ask_price_target_good']) or
                                         (x['running_bid_min'] <= x['ask_price_target_bad']), data_stream)
```

Whatever you will do with individual partitions is up to you (you can create addtional fields or columns etc.).

```py
print([(part[0]['time'], part[-1]['time'], 
        part[0]['running_bid_max'] > part[0]['ask_price_target_good'],
        part[0]['running_bid_min'] > part[0]['ask_price_target_bad']) 
       for part in partitions])
```

```
[('2019-07-24T07:59:46.393418', '2019-07-24T07:59:46.393418', False, False), 
 ('2019-07-24T07:59:44.432034', '2019-07-24T07:59:44.432034', False,  True), 
 ('2019-07-24T07:59:48.425615', '2019-07-24T07:59:54.428181', False, False), 
 ('2019-07-24T07:59:58.550378', '2019-07-24T08:00:57.338769', False,  True), 
 ('2019-07-24T08:00:59.058198', '2019-07-24T08:01:08.586688',  True,  True)]
```

Also note that it is easy to create individual `DataFrame`s

```
info_cols = ['running_bid_max', 'ask_price_target_good', 'running_bid_min', 'ask_price_target_bad', 'time'] 
data_frames = [pandas.DataFrame(_)[info_cols] for _ in partitions]
data_frames
```

```
   running_bid_max  ask_price_target_good  running_bid_min  ask_price_target_bad                        time
0            291.4                 291.53           291.09                291.13  2019-07-24T07:59:46.393418

   running_bid_max  ask_price_target_good  running_bid_min  ask_price_target_bad                        time
0            291.4                 291.46           291.09                291.06  2019-07-24T07:59:44.432034

   running_bid_max  ask_price_target_good  running_bid_min  ask_price_target_bad                        time
0            291.4                 291.53           291.09                291.13  2019-07-24T07:59:48.425615
1            291.4                 291.53           291.09                291.13  2019-07-24T07:59:50.084206
2            291.4                 291.53           291.09                291.13  2019-07-24T07:59:52.326455
3            291.4                 291.53           291.09                291.13  2019-07-24T07:59:54.428181

   running_bid_max  ask_price_target_good  running_bid_min  ask_price_target_bad                        time
0           291.40                 291.55            291.2                291.15  2019-07-24T07:59:58.550378
1           291.40                 291.55            291.2                291.15  2019-07-24T08:00:00.837238
2           291.51                 291.66            291.4                291.26  2019-07-24T08:00:57.338769

   running_bid_max  ask_price_target_good  running_bid_min  ask_price_target_bad                        time
0           291.96                 291.66           291.40                291.26  2019-07-24T08:00:59.058198
1           291.96                 291.66           291.40                291.26  2019-07-24T08:01:00.802679
2           291.96                 291.66           291.45                291.26  2019-07-24T08:01:02.781289
3           291.96                 291.66           291.45                291.26  2019-07-24T08:01:04.645144
4           292.07                 291.66           291.45                291.26  2019-07-24T08:01:06.491997
5           292.10                 291.66           291.45                291.26  2019-07-24T08:01:08.586688
```

Unfortunatly I couldn't find a one liner `pytition_by` for `DataFrame`. It surely is hidden somewhere. (But again, `pandas` usually loads all data into memory - if you want to aggregate during I/O than streaming could be a way to go.)

---

#### *Streaming Example

For example, lets us create a simple `csv` stream:

```py
def data_stream():
    with open('blubb.csv') as tsfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(tsfile, delimiter='\t')
        number_keys = [_ for _ in reader.fieldnames if _ != 'time']

        def update_values(data_item):
            for k in number_keys:
                data_item[k] = float(data_item[k])
            return data_item
        for row in reader:
            yield update_values(dict(row))
```

that yields one processed row at a time:

```
next(data_stream())

{'time': '2019-07-24T07:59:46.393418',
 'bid_price': 291.1,
 'ask_price': 291.33,
 'running_bid_max': 291.4,
 'running_bid_min': 291.09,
 'ask_price_target_good': 291.53,
 'ask_price_target_bad': 291.13}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure I correctly understand your problem. I provide below a solution to the following problem:

- For a given row (which I will call the current row), we keep all the rows whose time 
  is between the time of this row and the time of this row plus 5 minutes
- In the rows we have kept, we search if `running_bid_max` might be superior to the 
  value we have in the `ask_price_target_good` column of the current row
- If so, we keep the first occurrence of `running_bid_max` superior to
  `ask_price_target_good` of the current row

In your example, for row `0`, we have `291.46` in `ask_price_target_good`. At row `8` (whose time in within the time frame of 5 minutes from the time of row`0`), we find `291.51` (which is superior to `291.46`) and thus we would like to keep this value for row `0`.

A symmetric operation must be done for `running_bid_min` that must be tested to be inferior to `ask_price_target_bad`.

To solve this problem, I wrote the following code. I am not using `iterrows` but the `apply` function of `DataFrame`. Nevertheless, I need, for each row, to select a bunch of rows from the whole dataframe (the 5 minutes time window) before searching the lines that might be superior to `ask_price_target_good`. I hope this will be fast enough if you have large dataframes.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dtm

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", parse_dates=["time"])

TIME_WINDOW = 5*60

def over_target_good(row, dataframe):
    time_window = dataframe.time <= (row.time
                                     + dtm.timedelta(seconds=TIME_WINDOW))
    window_data = dataframe[time_window]
    over_test = window_data.running_bid_max >= row.ask_price_target_good
    over_data = window_data[over_test]
    if len(over_data) > 0:
        return over_data.running_bid_max[over_data.index[0]]
    return np.NaN

def below_target_bad(row, dataframe):
    time_window = dataframe.time <= (row.time
                                     + dtm.timedelta(seconds=TIME_WINDOW))
    window_data = dataframe[time_window]
    below_test = window_data.running_bid_min <= row.ask_price_target_bad
    below_data = window_data[below_test]
    if len(below_data) > 0:
        return below_data.running_bid_min[below_data.index[0]]
    return np.NaN

print("OVER\n", data.apply(over_target_good, axis=1, args=(data,)) )
print("BELOW\n", data.apply(below_target_bad, axis=1, args=(data,)) )
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
df['g']=np.NaN
df['l']=np.NaN
deep=len(df.index)
irange= np.arange(1,deep)

for i in irange:
    G=df.time[df.running_bid_max.shift(i)-df.ask_price_target_good>=0]
    G.index=G.index-i
    df['g']=df['g'].combine_first(G)

    L=df.time[df.running_bid_min.shift(i)-df.ask_price_target_bad<=0]
    L.index=L.index-i
    df['l']=df['l'].combine_first(L)
```

You can change the deep parameter (time window)

It can be optimized

Answer (score 1):

**Goal**

> creating a new timestamp column for when `running_bid_max` greater than or equal to the value in `ask_price_target_good`. Then create a separate timestamp column for when `running_bid_min` is less than or equal to  `ask_price_target_bad`

Try this :

```
import numpy as np

#   Setup conditions
conditions = [
  (df['running_bid_max'] >= df['ask_price_target_good']),
  (df['running_bid_min'] >= df['ask_price_target_bad'])]

#   Setup output (you could insert timestamp var here)
choices = ["Greater", "Lesser"]

#   Apply conditions
df['bid_value'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='N/A')
```

Hope this helps provide a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

you can just use:

```
df['time_bid_max_greater'] = df.time[df['running_bid_max'] >= df['ask_price_target_good']]

df['time_bid_min_less'] = df.time[df['running_bid_min'] <= df['ask_price_target_bad']]

df
```

[image]

Comment: @bbennett36 I just duplicate your given data till I got ~1mil rows and the process lasted less than 80 ms

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I think I understand. You want the value for each row to be the timestamp of the next date where these conditions are met? If so, you can build off of Quang's answer. Specifically, lets still do

```
df['g'] = np.where(df.running_bid_max.ge(df.ask_price_target_good), df['time'], pd.NaT)

df['l'] = np.where(df.running_bid_min.le(df.ask_price_target_bad), df['time'], pd.NaT)
```

Now, we can do:

```
 df['g'] = df['g'].fillna(method='bfill')
 df['l'] = df['l'].fillna(method='bfill')
```

Now you end up with timestamp from row 9 in row 0.

Is this what you are looking for?